# I need to return the string instead of True in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, filter, printing

I have a list of sentences and need to print the quotes with the 'theWord' include inside.
it returns True but I need to see the sentences.

```
myList = ["hello world","good boy","good night"]

theWord = "good"

theQuote = filter (==True) (map (isInfixOf theWord) myList)
```

output:

```
*Main> theQuote 

[True,True]
```

Comment: Even though it's not part of the solution here it's worth mentioning that you can, in general, replace `(==True)` with `id`.

Answer (score 3):

The `filter` takes a predicate to check what items to retain, you thus can use `isInfixOf theWord` as predicate:

```
theQuote :: [String]
theQuote = filter (isInfixOf theWord) myList
```

Answer (score 3):

`isInfix theWord` is the predicate to pass to `filter`, which should iterate over the list itself.

```
theQuote = filter (isInfixOf theWord) myList
```

Comment: thanks a lot guys